# Выполнение серверных сценариев без участия пользователя

Tags: php, servlet

Как это бывает?

Допустим, на PHP хочется скрипт сделать, который будет сам выполнятся в заданное время или, например, загрузил я файл конфигураций - скрипт видит это и выполняет настройки. Или рассылки.

Как все это делается, дополнительными модулями или языком программирования?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запуск по времени - это [cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
Насчет загрузил файл - в смысле по FTP загрузил? Можно запустить скрипт (не через браузер, конечно), который будет следить за изменениями в файловой системе, например.

Comment: Да, FTP. Я думал сложнее все делается...

Answer (score 0):

сложнее, еще с кроном разобраться надо!он еще те чудеса творит....